# PHP output to HTML from database

Tags: php, html, database, post, methods

I cant output the values of the row value to the html content any suggestions on how to do that? i tried using different methods so that i will print on the page but it's always blank is there any way  to do it?

```
<?php 

//connect
$dbh=mysql_connect ("localhost", "xxxx_admin", "xxxx") 
   or die ('I cannot connect to the database.');
 mysql_select_db ("xxxx_Client"); 

$term = $_POST['term'];
echo $term;

$sql = mysql_query("select * from ClientTable where FName like '$term'");

if ($row['FName'] == $term){

$ID = $row['ID'];
$FName = $row['FName'];
$LName = $row['LName'];
$PHON = $row['PHON'];

}

else
echo "invalid input";

?>

<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
asdadasdad<br>

<?php echo $FName; ?><br>a<br>
<?php echo $_POST["$LName"]; ?><br>a<br>

$FName <br>
$LName <br>
$ID <br>
$PHON <br>

sadasdasda
</bod>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you setting `$row`?

Comment: you need some sort of `$row = mysql_result($sql,0);` call  Incidentally, you should also use the mysqli_* functions as the mysql_* flavor are deprecated.

Comment: Take a look to these examples: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 1):

First, you are probably not getting any results from your query.  Typically when using `LIKE`  you use some form of wildcard in the query like this:

```
select * from ClientTable where FName like '%$term%'
```

Second, you are not actually working with the result set.

You need to use some sort of `mysql_fetch_array` or similar to get the values into $row.

And of course, you really should not be using the mysql_* functions anyway as they are being deprecated in favor of mysqli_* or PDO.

Finally, your need to learn how to prevent SQL injection.  Your code is vulnerable now.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` near the beginning of your code. There is a good chance that a notice message will tell you what you're doing wrong.